# YouTube API PHP - Like or Dislike video after authentication

Tags: youtube-api

I'm using PHP and Zend to pull in my videos from YouTube.  I'm authenticated with AuthSub and can post comments successfully.

I now wish to click on 'like' or 'dislike'.
The PHP API guide only has the old star rating detailed:
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_php.html#Adding_a_Rating

But how can I do the same thing for the new rating system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know the question is quite old, but hopefully my answer will be useful for anyone finding this post via Google.

The like/dislike element is documented at
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/reference.html#youtube_data_api_tag_yt:rating

and the protocol examples are at
http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_ratings.html

The documentation says that in order to dislike/like a video, you can send an authenticated POST request to the video's ratings URL and set the value to "like"/"dislike".

As an alternative to setting like/dislike in your request (i.e. when using a library that requires numeric input) you could also rely on the fact that a 1 rating in the older numeric rating system corresponds to a "dislike" and a 5 rating corresponds to a "like".

Hope I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Also for future reference, here's how the same sort of operation can be done using version 3 of the YouTube Data API: [YouTube API v3: Liking a video in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460699/youtube-api-v3-liking-a-video-in-python)