# How to Like Youtube Video with Youtube Api v3 using php

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

Since Youtube Api V2 doesn't support like a specific video anymore. Can anyone please explain how to like a video with youtube api v3 ?
I am always getting the following response:

```
 Response


400 Bad Request

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "youtube.part",
    "reason": "unexpectedPart",
    "message": "contentDetails",
    "locationType": "parameter",
    "location": "part"
   }
  ],
  "code": 400,
  "message": "contentDetails"
 }
}
```

The request is :

```
Request


POST https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=snippet&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Content-Type:  application/json
Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQUI8Gn7j93QZBmmdlDe7Ei-iqYseYAKAxyf3qTOHHwDHb-dA
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer

{
 "contentDetails": {
  "like": {
   "resourceId": {
    "videoId": "video-id",
    "kind": "youtube#video"
   }
  }
 }
}
```

The part is = snippet

I am following these docs : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/insert

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460699/youtube-api-v3-liking-a-video-in-python .. describes which headers you need to pass ...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is already in the comments, but to elevate it a bit: [YouTube API v3: Liking a video in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13460699/youtube-api-v3-liking-a-video-in-python) has more information about liking a video, though the example there is in Python.

The important part is that liking a video is done via a `playlistItems.insert()` call, not an `activities.insert()` call. This is a common source of confusion and I've already asked our tech writer to try to clear things up in the docs.